# Can someone help me create variables for the print statements?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, boto3

I am not good at creating variables, especially for this difficult piece of code.

```
    topic_page = client.get_paginator('list_topics').paginate()
    for topic in list(topic_page)[0]['Topics']:
        try:
          subscriptions_page = client.get_paginator('list_subscriptions_by_topic').paginate(TopicArn=topic.get('TopicArn'))
          if list(subscriptions_page):
              for subscription in list(subscriptions_page)[-1]['Subscriptions']:
                  try:
                    *print('TopicArn', subscription['TopicArn'])
                    print('Protocol -', subscription['Protocol'])
                    print('SubscriptionArn', subscription['SubscriptionArn'])*
                  except:
                      pass
```

I want to create variables for the print statements.

Comment: It's not at all obvious what you mean by "create variables" here. Do you just want your `subscription[...]` bits to be in variables before you print them? Or something else? Can you give an example of what you want in some other context, maybe?

Comment: @Blckknght Hi, sorry i am clear with erxplain what i need. But yes I'd like  

`print('TopicArn', subscription['TopicArn'])
                    print('Protocol -', subscription['Protocol'])
                    print('SubscriptionArn', subscription['SubscriptionArn'])`

to be in variables before printed.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your clarification in a comment, it's still not exactly clear what you want to do. In Python, there's no good way to make a variable named after a string in another variable (it's not *impossible*, but the ways to do it are usually bad ideas). Variable names are supposed to be for programmers to interact with. They're not data themselves. For data, you want a data structure, like the `subscription` dictionaries you're already dealing with.

But that doesn't mean you can't streamline your code, perhaps using some variables. At the simplest, you could just do some assignments before printing, so you could do something else with the values other than print them, if you wanted to:

```
topic_arn = subscription['TopicArn']
protocol = subscription['Protocol']
subscription_arn = subscription['SubscriptionArn']

print('TopicArn', topic_arn)
print('Protocol -', protocol)
print('SubscriptionArn', subscription_arn)

# do other stuff down here with the variables, if you want
```

But that's *more* code than what you have, and maybe you want less code instead. If you don't want to hard-code the keys to get from the dictionary, you could instead iterate over the ones that exist, printing each one out with its value:

```
for key, value in subscriptions.items():
    print(key, value)
```

That's a whole lot simpler! But it might print keys and values you don't want if the dictionary contains extra stuff, or iterate the desired keys in the wrong order. So we could instead iterate over a tuple of the keys we want to show, and print them with their corresponding values:

```
key_list = 'TopicArn', 'Protocol', 'SubscriptionArn' # this could be defined somewhere earlier

for key in key_list:
     print(key, subscription[key])
```

This might not print out exactly what you want, if you need special presentation for some keys and not others (e.g. the `-` in the middle of the output for the protocol). You could probably add extra stuff to the tuple if you really wanted to have customizable output.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually figured it out yesterday and did it similar to your first example. I will refer back to this often. Very helpful. @Blckknght